# SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Description', table 'dbo.Shifts'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to insert parent data only, not child object. Related foreign key property object is null, but still EF core is trying to insert child object. Here is my objects -

```
public class Shift
{
    public int ShiftUID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AOCSchedule> AOCSchedules { get; set; }
}

public class AOCSchedule
{
    public int AOCUID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScheduleDate { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public int ShiftUID { get; set; }
    public Shift Shift { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my Add method -

```
public async Task<AOCSchedule> AddAOCScheduleAsync(AOCSchedule entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(entity.Shift).State = EntityState.Detached;
        await _dbContext.Set<AOCSchedule>().AddAsync(entity);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return entity;
    }
```

Since there is no data in child object (Shift), so it throws the exception. Also I tried marking child entity state as Unmodified, but didn't work. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would start by looking at what entities the Context is currently tracking. (see: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/changetracker-in-ef-core.aspx)  If the Shift reference had been tracked along with it's collection of other Schedules and any of those schedules were modified in any way, the Shift could be persisted that way. An entity should always reflect the complete data state and ideally not be passed to a view or other consumer where they don't need  complete data. (Use a ViewModel) Detaching/ignoring entities piecemeal like this leads to brittle code.

Answer (score 0):

The models you use is that Shift is parent and AOCSchedule is child. EFCore doesn't allow to save child data without parent's data. That's why you get error. You need to re-design your database if you want AOCSchedule to be parent table.

For example, remove ShiftUID from AOCSchedule and add AOCUID in Shift table.

Comment: Shift must be parent and AOC must be child. Relationship is fine I think. Also Shift table has already data. However issue has been fixed as I had to set null to Shift property explicitly just to inform EF, I don't want to insert Shift data, but only AOC data. I think its my mistake as I have written parent as AOC and child as Shift in question. I will correct it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**1. Just make the foreign key `nullable`:**

```
public class AOCSchedule
{
    public int AOCUID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScheduleDate { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; } 

    public int? ShiftUID { get; set; }       //public int ShiftUID { get; set; }
    public virtual Shift Shift { get; set; } //public Shift Shift { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

**2. Comment out this line because this is no shift posted from view**

```
_dbContext.Entry(entity.Shift).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

> Codes of controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddAOCScheduleAsync([Bind("AOCUID,ScheduleDate,StartTime,EndTime,ShiftUID,Name,IsActive")] AOCSchedule entity)
    {

        //_dbContext.Entry(entity.Shift).State = EntityState.Detached;
        await _dbContext.Set<AOCSchedule>().AddAsync(entity);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        //return entity;
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

    }
```

> Test of result

[image]